# vue-jstree не открывает children при загрузке данных по api

Tags: vue.js, api

Данные подгружаются в store по api, в компоненте я получаю данные в таком формате:`

```
[ { "id": 1, "title": "Заголовок 1",
     "parts": 
            [ { "id": 1,  "title": "Запчасть 1" }, 
              { "id": 2,  "title": "Запчасть 2" }.... и т.д.
```

Само дерево выглядит так:

```
                                        <v-jstree :data="data"
                                                  childrenFieldName="parts"
                                                  textFieldName="title"
                                                  @item-click="itemClick"
                                        />
```

Данные в дерево подгружаются все... Но родительский список не открывается...
Как только я использую статические данные всё работает:

```
   data() {
        return {
            data: [
                {
                    "title": "Заголовок 1",

                    "parts": [
                        {
                            "title": "Запчасть 1",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Запчасть 2",
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }

        },
```

В чем может быть проблема? Не всплывает какое то событие при загрузке данных по api..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом проб нашел способ решения) в ответе сервера, в родителе должен быть указан параметр `"opened"` либо **true**, либо **false**